# Cannot View Audit Logs: Stream FireStore to BigQuery Extension

Tags: google-bigquery, audit-logging

I am using the Stream FireStore to BigQuery extension (https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/firestore-bigquery-export) for one collection. When I insert some records in that collection, it successfully moves data from FireStore to BigQuery. But, I am not able to view Logs of BigQuery Data Insertion in a table.

I have tried accessing the logs with different Roles like Logs Viewer, Logs Admin, and Private Logs Viewer.

When I insert some records in a Table from Google Cloud Big Query Explorer, it generates the Logs as desired.

I want the logs from Extension to Trigger a 2nd Gen Cloud Function to perform some processing. Is there any other way of doing it?